# UIBarButtonItem action not working.Why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Thanks to all. I found really working code. It looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     UIButton* infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
     [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(settingsClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

     UIBarButtonItem* theSettingsButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:infoButton];

     [self.toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:theSettingsButton,nil]];

     [theSettingsButton release];
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, is going wrong? Does the code compile? does the button appear? does pressing it do nothing? does pressing it cause your app to crash?

Comment: and is what do you get if you do `NSLog(@"%@", self.toolBar)` is it `nil`; have you wired it up correctly in interface builder?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *theSettingsButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                           initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                           target:self action:@selector(settingsClick)] autorelease];

}

-(void)settingsClick
{    
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}
```

You hadn't closed your viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIBarButtonItem *theSettingsButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                  target:self action:@selector(settingsClick)]autorelease];
NSMutableArray * arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:theSettingsButton, nil];
[self.toolbar setToolbarItems:arr animated:YES];
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

```
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 380, 320, 40)];
UIBarButtonItem *theSettingsButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                       initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                       target:self action:@selector(settingsClick)]autorelease];
NSArray * arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:theSettingsButton, nil];
[toolbar setItems:arr animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
```

Comment: That would move the button from the toolbar at the bottom of the screen to the navigation bar at the top - useful to test if the button's action is working but doesn't quite answer the question :)